# Safari Scrolling issue with jQuery .remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, safari, scroll

I'm developing a plugin for a website building program, and am building the preview page for it. It's sort of a parallax scrolling plugin and the issue I'm having is that in Safari, when you scroll down to a certain point, it wont allow you to scroll any further. It's fine in firefox and chrome, but I saw the same issue in opera. I've managed to narrow it down to the function that's causing it, but I have no idea why or how to fix it.

When I comment out this function, the page scrolls fine, but it doesn't remove the empty divs like I need it to do:

```
function removeStuff() {
    $('.conP').each(function(){
        var divDad = $(this),
            divses = $(this).children();
        if (divses.hasClass('empty'))
            divDad.remove();
    });
}
```

here's the preview page where the issue can be observed:
http://reveriesrefined.com/myftp/dack_stev/

***//////////EDIT:***

I've simplified the code to this:

```
$('.conP_%id% > .empty').parent().remove();
```

however, it's still causing scrolling issues in safari and opera, but not the other browsers.

Any help is VERY VERY appreciated!

Comment: For me, the scrolling issues begin once I get to the storm troopers head.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the issue already. Somehow even though commenting out the function mentioned above seemed to solve it, it was actually a line of code in another function.

I had this function:

```
function autoPlay() {
var backDiv = $('#outterLax div:first');
    backDiv.hide();
    $('.conP').hide();
    backDiv.remove();
    $('#outterLax').append(backDiv);
    backDiv.show();
}
```

but the line:

```
$('.conP').hide();
```

was unnecessary as that was already being accomplished elsewhere in my code.